# Does Visual Studio Code autodetect task.json files within the project

Tags: visual-studio-code

From the documentation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks it hints that Visual Code will autodetect various project tasks such as gulp, grunt and npm. However it is not clear whether or not Visual Code will detect task.json files nested inside a project.

Currently, I can only define the task.json file in .vscode/ which is not distributed within the repository. Is there a way to include project specific task.json files outside of .vscode?

Comment: If you believe this should work, please file an issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Comment: @MattBierner somewhat of a chicken or the egg problem. I have a questions on whether it should work this way, I don't know that it should. However, if it should work this way, it is either a bug or the documentation isn't clear on how to do it. I can file a bug if the documentation is incomplete.

Comment: If you think this should work—either because the documentation says so or because it seems like it should work—its safe to call it a bug (either one in the docs or in the code)